# Java send to all sockets

Tags: java, sockets

Im making a chat program.
i got the client to server connection working but i cant get the server to send to all sockets. Since Im using ObjectOutputStream i cant use PrintWriter which was the way I did it before, Heres my code thanks for the help

Server

```
import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Server {
    public Server clients[] = new Server[50];
    public static String user;
    private static final int PORT = 4000;
    private static HashSet<String> names = new HashSet<String>();

    private static HashSet<PrintWriter> writers = new HashSet<>(); 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("The chatroom is running...");
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        try{
            while(true){
                new Handler(listener.accept()).start();

            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }
        finally{
            listener.close();
        }
    }



    private static class Handler extends Thread{
        private String name;       
        private Socket socket;
        //private BufferedReader in;
        //private PrintWriter out;
        public ObjectOutputStream out;
        public ObjectInputStream in;



        public void send(Message msg) throws IOException{
            out.writeObject(msg);
            out.flush();            
        }


        public void Announce(String type, String sender, String content){
            Message msg = new Message(type, sender, content, "All");


        }

        public Handler(Socket socket){
            this.socket = socket;
        }

        public void run(){
            try {

                out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                out.flush();
                in = (new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));  

                out.writeObject(new Message("SUBMITNAME", "blank", "blank", "blank"));
                while(true){                    
                    Message msg = (Message) in.readObject();
                    if(msg.sender == null){
                        return;
                    }
                    if(!names.contains(msg.sender)){
                        names.add(msg.sender);
                        System.out.println(names.toString());
                        System.out.println("The object is " + msg);

                    }  
                    break;
                }
                while(true){
                    Message msg = (Message) in.readObject();
                    System.out.println(msg);
                    names.add(msg.sender);
                    System.out.println(names.toString());
                    break;
                }
                //out.writeObject(new Message("MESSAGE", "Server", "Welcome To the ChatRoom", "c"));
                while(true){                    

                    Message msg = (Message) in.readObject();
                    if(msg.type.equals("MESSAGE")){
                        out.writeObject(new Message("MESSAGE", msg.sender, msg.content, "all"));                       
                        System.out.println(msg.sender + ": " + msg.content);
                    }
                }



            } 
            catch (Exception e) {

                System.err.println(e);
            }     
            finally{
                try{
                    socket.close();
                    System.out.println("Socket has closed");
                }
                catch(IOException e){
                    System.err.println("Problem closing socket!");
                }
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Client

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret;
import static javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE;

public class Client  implements Serializable{
    //private BufferedReader in;
    //private PrintWriter out;

    ObjectOutputStream out;
    ObjectInputStream in;
    String name;

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Client Box");

    JTextField textField = new JTextField(40);
    JTextArea messageArea = new JTextArea(8,40);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(messageArea);
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();


    public Client(){

        textField.setEditable(false);
        messageArea.setEditable(false);
        messageArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        messageArea.setLineWrap(true);
        DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) messageArea.getCaret();
        caret.setUpdatePolicy(ALWAYS_UPDATE);

        //frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);   
        frame.pack();

        textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){                
                try{
                    //Message msg = new Message("MESSAGE", name, textField.getText(), "all");
                    //out.writeObject(msg);
                    sendAll("MESSAGE", name, textField.getText());
                    textField.setText("");
                }catch(IOException ex){System.err.println(ex.printStackTrace()};

            }
        });      
    }


    public void sendAll(String type, String sender, String content) throws IOException{
        Message msg = (new Message(type, sender, content, "all"));
        out.writeObject(msg);
        out.flush();
    }

    private String getName(){
        return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Your Screen Name?", "Please Enter Screen Name: "
                , JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
    private String getMessage(){
        return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Your message?", "Please Enter Screen Name: "
                , JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }

    private void run() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        //String address = getServerAddress();
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 4000);
        in = (new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        Message temp = (Message) in.readObject();

        if(temp.type.equals("SUBMITNAME")){
            textField.setEditable(true);
            name = getName();
            sendAll(name, "a", " b");
        }
        while(true){
            Message msg = (Message) in.readObject();
            messageArea.append(msg.sender + ": " + msg.content + "\n");

        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException{
        Client client = new  Client();
        client.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        client.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        client.frame.setVisible(true);
        try {
        try {
            client.run();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: tcp are connection oriented so u can send msg to other by first disconnecting the connected client

Comment: i want to send a message to all of them

Comment: you want to broadcast - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html

Comment: If you already got all connected sockets, just write what you want to the sockets.

Comment: you need to use udp in place of tcp for broadcasting

Comment: I want the sockets to write to eachother so... Client to Server To All Clients

Comment: when listening to clients (Handler) you can put (add) any incoming handler into a list and then send a message to all clients in that list...

Comment: like an ArrayList? or is there a better list to use